# Local storage: MySQL vs. JSON?

Tags: mysql, json, local-storage

I'm working on an app that's going to be parsing, processing, and formatting a lot of data blocks (stellar position and brightness data). A single night of data can have a dozen files, each consisting of several hundred lines. I have two options for storage and access of the raw data: database (MySQL) or JSON files. This is all in a local environment, so bandwidth and request times are virtually negligible - but I don't know enough about either option to say which is optimal.

Can you, the enlightened SO community, share your knowledge as to whether or not one is the clear choice? I don't really need to fragment the data, so MySQL's relational capabilities are moot - just wondering if one is faster or more lightweight.

(Tried my best to dodge the "which is better" taboo - if I can reword or clarify, please let me know!)

---

**EDIT**: Seriously, anonymous close votes are not helpful. I'd like to learn how to form my questions better so as not to waste everyone's time - tell what I can do to change it!

Comment: If you're dealing with files, then why can't you just save them to your server directly. This way, you won't have to worry about the overhead due to SQL queries or due to retrieval from JSON.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya .json and .sql are the two export options for this data. Even if I had raw text files, I'd have to parse them manually and account for possible exceptions to data patterns - JSON at least gets loaded into an object.

Comment: I think the biggest question here is "How will you be accessing this data after once having saved it?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're always going to be saving and loading entire data sets, and don't need to do complex queries, JSON is probably the simpler and more efficient method. But if you really want to be sure, you should benchmark them.

There are also databases with less overhead than MySQL, such as SQLite.

Answer (score 5):

Are you going to be consistently loading and using the ENTIRE data-set, or will you only really want part of it?

Use a database (mySql or Sqlite or whatever) if you want something the database gives you, specifically in this case the ability to query your data-set.  (security and normalization and standardization ate nice, too.)

Use a raw file (csv, xml, json) if you don't want anything a database provides, and want to load he entire data-set into memory anyway.

Comment: Thanks Doug! The only time I'm going to be loading data is to analyze the entire block as a whole, so querying is irrelevant - guess I'm going with json!